# jQuery iPhone slide that moves background image but red bar stays in middle

Tags: jquery, image, background, slider

I have this image:

[image: FM tuner]

What I want to do is turn it into a slider for iPhone users to move their finger side to side and change the channel.

Would a slider do this? I understand the slider knob moving but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer JQuery Ui, you will also need "JQuery Ui touch punch" for touchstart and touchend events.
Jquery Ui slider doesn't work on touch screens out of the box.

http://furf.com/exp/touch-punch/.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the background image, which is what slides, and the little red bar that stays in the same place, each as different images. To determine what channel is selected, you could check to see which part of the image is in the viewport. [This library](http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery UI, you'd be able to make the image a div sitting behind a static line (using css zindexes for which is on top).

You'd be able to constrain the movement of the image to just the horizontal axis with the `{axis:'x'}` option.

To get what 'station' is selected, you're going to need to do some conversions between your images pixel locations and the overall position of the image. Check out the `drag event` listed under the [jQuery UI Docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#default). the relative position to the parent object is given by `ui.position`